# Rule rewrite module

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I'm new in C# ASP.net and i trying to do something where i'm doing my University social Service.

I made a couple of rules for a web solution but i don't know why it doesn't working

```
<rule name="Clean url">
    <match url="^/Inicio$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/home" />
  </rule>
<rule name="Clean solicitud">
    <match url="^/Usuario/Solicitud$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/Usuario/Solicitudes" />
  </rule>
```

Here are some images:

[image]

[image]

My boss told me that there's another solution but in AJAX? Could someone help me?

Comment: Try it without the first slash `^Inicio$` and `^Usuario/Solicitud$`

Comment: I tried but didn't work :/